# Solution of $\frac{dx}{dt}=0,1x(1-x)-0,03(1+\sin(2\pi t))$ I

Tags: differential-equations

I want solve differential equation: $\frac{dx}{dt}=0,1x(1-x)-0,03(1+\sin(2\pi t))$

```
DSolve[x'[t] == 0.1*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 0.03*(1 + Sin[2*Pi*t]), x[t], t]
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: You can give it an initial condition and use `NDSolve` to get a numerical solution, or you can use Maple to do it.  You get Mathieu functions.

Comment: Do you expect a real solution? If so the asymptotic solution `xa` solves `0== 0.1*xa[t]*(1 - xa[t]) - 0.03*(1 + Sin[2*Pi*t])`   which isn't real!!! Please check your ode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AsymptoticDSolveValue` to obtain series solution.

```
ClearAll[x, t]
ode = x'[t] == 1/10*x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 3/100*(1 + Sin[2*Pi*t]);
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, x[t], {t, 0, 3}];
sol /. C[1] -> x[0]
```

$$
\frac{t^3 \left(-150 x(0)^4+300 x(0)^3-235 x(0)^2+300 \pi  x(0)+85 x(0)-150 \pi -12\right)}{150000}+\frac{t^2 \left(20 x(0)^3-30 x(0)^2+16 x(0)-60 \pi
   -3\right)}{2000}+\frac{1}{100} t \left(-10 x(0)^2+10 x(0)-3\right)+x(0)
$$

Which is the same as Maple's

```
restart;
ode:=diff(x(t),t)=1/10*x(t)*(1-x(t))-3/100*(1+sin(2*Pi*t));
Order:=3;
dsolve(ode,x(t),'series')
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]